# How export an Eclipse project including IBM classes for Java libraries into an executable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, websphere, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to export an `Eclipse` project to a `JAR` executable file.
This project include a personal library with two IBM packages `com.ibm.mq.jar` and `com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar`

There are no errors running the application from `Eclipse` run button or by command: `java MainClass` from the project bin folder.

Unfortunately once the jar is created (File > Export >  Runnable Jar) and launched `java -jar MainClass.jar` this is the result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/ResourceException
        at com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.<clinit>(MQEnvironment.java:520)
        at MQtestMain.<init>(MQtestMain.java:38)
        at MQtestMain.main(MQtestMain.java:18)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

I have tried also `Fat Jar` plugin for the export but the result of `java -jar MainClass_fat.jar` is quite similar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/ResourceException
        at com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.<clinit>(MQEnvironment.java:520)
        at MQtestMain.<init>(MQtestMain.java:38)
        at MQtestMain.main(MQtestMain.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

Which is the correct way to export and run an `Eclipse` project to a `Jar` file including `IBM MQ Classes for Java` libraries?

---

**Update 1:** Unecessary but very useful to reach the solution.

Suggested by Integrating Stuff:
Include `javaee.jar` file from the Java EE installation to import all dependencies for IBM classes jar included into the project.

---

**Solution:** Respect all the IBM classes for Java dependencies.

Import into the custom library **ALL** the `jar` file from `C:\...\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib`
 export as runnable Jar from `Eclipse` (Fat Jar plugin is not needed also)

Comment: Always for a "ClassNotFoundException" find out where the missing class belongs.  Eclipse can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Respect all the IBM classes for Java dependencies.

I've found very useful *Integrating Stuff* suggest to include `javaee.jar` file from the Java EE installation to import all dependencies for IBM classes jar included into the project.
This doesn't resolve the error he but has led me to the solution:

Import into the custom library **ALL** the `jar` file from `C:\...\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib`
 export as runnable Jar from `Eclipse` (Fat Jar plugin is not needed also)

Answer (score 2):

javax.resource.ResourceException is part of the Java EE api.

Your Eclipse project probably assumes this jar is going to be available in the target environment/does not have the java-ee api in its list of jars to package with the application.

Which build tool are you using? Maven or Ant, or are you packaging in Eclipse itself, without using an external tool?

To solve the problem, you need to make sure the Java EE api jar is included in your executable jar.

Comment: my eclipse is 
`Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722`
and Java is the last JDK 7.

My project include a personal library which is possible to pack with the JAR while the "standard" JRE System Library, automatically set with the project, seems to be not possible to include.
Do you think this is the cause of my errors?

Comment: No, the standard JRE System Library should never be included. Can you maybe try to add the following dependency to your package: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/6.0

Comment: I have included your jar into my library but it does't work (see my update on the main question).
Do you think I could try with some `java -Djava.library.path` or `-classpath` options launching the application?

Comment: Well, apparently, the dependency I posted can't be used for executable packages like this. Please read http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/. You need to download Java EE http://java.sun.com/javaee/ and take the javaee.jar from the lib folder of that download.

Comment: I've tried but the errors still remain. I want to point out that I have no problem running an exported Jar for projects which not use IBM Classes for Java libraries. It seems like Jar file or java launcher cannot find them "outside eclipse". Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: The ibm classes you are using that have the javax class as an underlying dependency, so it is normal you get this problem when using them. What happens if you include the other javaee.jar in your executable? Still the ClassFormatError?

Comment: Yes, exactly like the first try without it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any onlie guide on how to write a basic websphere client application with eclipse...
...Now I have found the solution (obviously it was my fault) thinking at what you've said "the problem isn't in the library imported but in their dependencies" I have included into my custom library all IMB java jar. It's done. I'm sorry if I took you too much time on this my trivial error. PS. I've updated my original question with all the comments consideration.

Comment: I guess it were other ClassNotFoundExceptions after you included the java.sun.com/javaee javaee.jar no?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your support. I've tried to vote up your answer but unfortunately I have less than 15 reputation points (I will do it soon)